# In ionic what add to description and autor tags located in config.xml file. What are they for?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I would like to know what is the proper content for `description` and `author` tags. They are in `config.xml` file.

How is this content going to be used? Is that read somehow by apple app store and/or google play?

```
<name>My App</name>
<description>
    An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
</description>
<author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
    Your Name Here
</author>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#description) of the config.xml file:

> Description specifies metadata that may appear within app-store listings.

and

> Author specifies contact information that may appear within app-store listings.

So, yes, it seem a fair assumption that they will be read by the App Store, Google Play, BlackBerry World etc., when the app is published there.

Comment: But we don't know / have a proof that is being use right? Thanks anyway

Comment: A proof? I don't understand - it says so in the documentation. And all app worlds have a description and an author for the apps they list.

Comment: I say because the _may_... Besides I released an app (with default description and author) to google play and app store and that data is not shown

Comment: You're right, it does say "may" in the documentation. Don't know man, I guess some app worlds might ask you for these details later on during the publication process, but in a general sense, that's what these fields are for.